# How to specify $* in a parameter for a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that has a test.excludes parameter that I would like to default to **/*$* (ie exclude all inner classes). Normally I would specify this value in a file, but in this case, I don't want to submit any files since this is investigative work (as I see tests that are failing, I will add them to test.excludes).

The problem is that the $* in **/*$* is being expanded to the command line variables. Using **/*$$* only changes the problem to $$ being expanded to the pid. Escaping * using \ doesn't work (inner classes are still run). Escaping by wrapping the entire value in ' does nothing to prevent the $* from being replaced.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1):

The following really ugly expression works: $(echo '**/*$*').